# What's the difference between "tagging", "labelling", and "annotation"?

Tags: verbs, differences

For machine learning purpose, we need to use labelled data to train a model. But what's the best verb to describe the action to "labelling" the data?

I have seen people using these terms, what's the difference between "tagging", "labelling", and "annotation"?

Comment: Are you sure English has much to do with machine learning? In ordinary English *tagging* and *labelling* are broadly the same; *annotation* quite different.

We might, eg, give a car a *tag* or *label* simply saying *Ford* or *saloon* or *current* but an *annotation* about that car might say, eg, *The best-selling car in history*.

The one is a simple fact or arbitrary choice; the other some kind of explanatory information about that fact or choice.

How that translates to machine learning, I have no idea.

Comment: I was reading this article about data labeling. It uses all 3 terms (tag, label, annotation) for the same concept. https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/datascience/how-to-organize-data-labeling-for-machine-learning-approaches-and-tools/

Comment: It all depends on the jargon used in your corner of the internet.

Comment: I think of labelling as descriptions of the dataset as a whole. Tagging as the calling out of specific attributes of the dataset and  annotations as pointing out specific features within a dataset.  Here is a dataset labelled “Car 106 5/30/2020”  it is tagged, highway, sunny, light traffic, road construction.  Within it are two annotated pedestrians, a bicycle, three road signs etc.   Of course that’s not how everyone uses them.